# google protocol buffer wire type start group and end group usage

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Trying to parse a message from a server which passes wire type as Start Group .
I am using protobuf-c lib in which start group and end group are unsupported (Latest).Is there any examples how to work with wire type as start group so that can parse the message by my self

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For background, "groups" are a different way of representing a sub-message. They are declared like this:

```
message Foo {
  repeated group bar = 1 {
    optional int32 baz = 2;
    optional string qux = 3;
  }
}
```

Semantically, this is almost exactly the same as:

```
message Foo {
  repeated Bar bar = 1;
  message Bar {
    optional int32 baz = 2;
    optional string qux = 3;
  }
}
```

However, the encoding is slightly different (explained below).

Groups were already deprecated at the time that Protobuf was first open sourced, hence a lot of non-Google implementations don't support groups. Google has some very old protocols that still use groups, but probably no one outside of Google should be using groups, so I'm guessing the protocol you're working with is one of Google's. (If not, maybe you just have corrupted data.)

I'll assume you've already read [the encoding docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), but they don't explain groups.

Groups are encoded starting with a "start group" tag, followed by the sub-message content, followed by a corresponding "end group" tag. This is the only case in protobufs where a tag appears at the end of a value -- in all other cases a tag only appears at the start.

In contrast, normal sub-messages (as in the second example above) are encoded using the "length-delimited" wire type: a tag, followed by the sub-message size, followed by the content. Notice how the length-delimited encoding means you can skip a sub-message without parsing all of its fields; with a group, the only way to know where the group ends is to parse every field until you see the end-group tag.

Comment: Thanks for the info this help me a lot .

Comment: The link no longer documents the wire format of groups. Could anyone knowledgeable please update the answer to show the binary representation of a simple embedded message and the equivalent group encoding of the same message?

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer The link never did document groups, which is why I said "but they don't explain groups", and then I explained the encoding in the next paragraph. There's no such thing as "the equivalent group encoding" of a sub-message. Group encoding is only used to encode groups, which are declared differently from sub-messages (see example above).